# How can we assemble a prepared statement recursively

Tags: c#, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm currently building a little tool to build MySQL Request, (yeah I know that a lot of them already exist, it's not the goal of the question).

At the moment I just create my query as a String that I concatenate recursively and then execute which isn't the proper way to do.

I'm aware of the use of prepared Query that can be helpful, but are they needed for a security reason like they are in php with PDO ?

My problem is that my recursive building build:

1. Each condition
2. Each bloc of condition with conditions
3. The complete Where element
4. Join elements
5. Imbricated query (union / intersect ...)
6. Selected field & function used
7. Complete query as a string reusing every previous builds

I mean by recursively (which isn't the correct word)

- I call BuildQuery() for my query
- it call BuildQuery() for where element
- where element call BuildQuery() for blocs
- blocs call BuildQuery() for Condition
- Condition can call BuildQuery() for a subobject (a SELECT with a IN condition
- for example)

(All these BuildQuery() come from a common Interface that every object implement)

Which make the use of prepared query difficult, because I don't see how I can prepare just parts of my query and assemble every part at the end with a prepared query.

I'm looking for a way to build my prepared statement in several times. My first idea was to has each BuildQuery that return a struct with a string with the request and a dictionary of parameters. Assemble them as they come and when finishing the build assembling this string and those parameters as a prepared query. Is this a good way to do, or is there something else that can be cleaner ?

Comment: It's not a good idea to simply use string concatenation to build a query if you're not properly validating your inputs, that's how you fall victim to an SQL Injection attack.

Comment: @dahui that's the goal of the question, I know that's a problem and that's why I'm looking for a solution ^^

Comment: Have a read of option 4 on this article: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet. If that doesn't put you off not using prepared statements, then good luck rolling your own security

Comment: I assume you're asking if its okay to NOT used prepared sql in some cases.  Well, as an opinion, i would try to avoid it at all costs.  And like @dahui mentioned, you shouldnt use if if the inputs are not properly validated.  BUT.... if you are confident that you're properly validating them, then I guess its okay but you have to be very confident and know exactly what you're doing. Good luck.

Comment: @KennethGarza Actually you already answer to something that I didn't write explicitly: A friend told me that .NET prepared statement were only needed to be able to redo easily the query and hadn't any security use which seems wrong for me but I wasn't sure as a parralel with php prepared statement.

In this case, I now understand that prepared statement are needed. Then I must find a way to assemble it during the building. I'll Edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't entirely clear, but since you are asking if it is really necessary to use prepared statements, it suggests to me that you are not in a position to roll your own version of SQL security. If this is a private DB storing your own data or trivial data, then I guess you could practice rolling your own. If this DB is going to be a production DB though, accessible through the internet, or storing personal data, then you really need to follow best security practices, and shouldn't write your own security, **even if you know what you're doing**.

[This article](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) suggests for C# the best practice is to use parameterized queries. Basically you write out the query as a string, but then add the parameters separately, the example code below is from the article. I'd recommend you read through the article to get a better understanding of SQL Injection and how to prevent it.

```
String query = 
     "SELECT account_balance FROM user_data WHERE user_name = ?";
 try {
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("customerName", CustomerName Name.Text));
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    // …
 } catch (OleDbException se) {
    // error handling
 }
```

Comment: By the comments on the question, I understood that yes, prepared statement must be used (yes I'm not here to do the security part). It's more about how can I build the statement during my building process or should I just do like I described at the end. (I edited my question since your answer)